# Publish npm Package for React

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have been attempting to publish an npm package for react but keep running into issues. More specifically, after I publish my package and go to test it, the installed package has errors related to the jsx.

I built the published package with `create-react-app` and then added an additional `package.json` in the specific directory I wanted to publish.

I assume my issues are because `create-react-app` expects you to use the `root` `package.json` and not a separate one within the project. So this leads me to believe there are Webpack or Babel configurations I need to handle. I am having trouble finding this information.

The directory I am trying to publish only has 3 files other than my `package.json` which looks like this

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "index.js",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": []
}
```

this has so far been unsuccessful. I have also attempted the following

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "index.js",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": []
}
```

Im not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library) for creating packages for React and publishing those to NPM.